# i am getting error while building app using python kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am trying to build an android app using kivy but when I give this command

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

I am getting an error like  `ERROR`:

> You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help
>   install")`

Answer (score 0):

First you should run: `buildozer init`
Then configure `buildozer.spec` with log level 2
After that run `buildozer -v android debug` to see all the errors displayed.